# Logistic model using Bootstrap

Tags: r, logistic-regression, statistics-bootstrap

i'm trying to create a logistic model using `boot()` function.
My dependent variable (factor:0,1) has a low number of defaults (were the dependent variable is = 1), so when using `boot()` some of the samples dont have any defaults, so i get an when trying to bootstrap. 
I  have tried changing the proportion of 1 and 0 in the dependent variable but I fear this changes my model
is there a way to solve this?

thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What are you getting out of the bootstrap?

Comment: this is the function im using while bootstrapping:    bs<-function(formula,data,indices){
    a1<-data[indices,]
    model<-glm(formula,data=a1,family="binomial")
    return(coef(model))
    }
    
    resultados<-boot(data=a,statistic=bs,R=1000,formula=int~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4)

Comment: Since you're new to SO, please carefully read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) and then update your question to conform to these guidelines.